# Cancel not visible on MFMessageComposeViewController in blue color navigation bar

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

In my application my navigation bar color is blue.

While opening `MFMessageComposeViewController` its cancel button color is also blue so user is not able to see cancel button.

Cancel button is performing action, i cam dismiss `MFMessageComposeViewController` by clicking it.

Is there any way i can change cancel button color other than blue?

Answer (score 1):

try this code.

```
MFMailComposeViewController* mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];        
mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailViewController setToRecipients:@[@"email@apple.com"]];

[mailViewController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

[self presentViewController:mailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

chagning `tintColor` of navigationBar should work

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
messageController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: How can i set the navigation bar color in case of presenting MFMessageComposeViewController ??

Comment: [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]]; try this before initialising MFMessageComposeViewController

Answer (score 0):

Just do this on the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or just before instantiating your controller

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```